# Custom Controls: Add custom button click logic within a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, custom-controls

I am creating an on-screen keyboard Custom Control that sends text to a target `TextBox`. Inside this keyboard, I am laying out custom `KeyboardKey` button controls that have an associated text output or keyboard keypress (Backspace, Arrow Keys, etc.).

Currently, I have defined a bunch of different controls and hard-coded their `Click` functionality inside of the control template:

```cs
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    Click += (s, e) =>
    {
        keyboard.Target.Focus(); // Focus on parent keyboard's TextBox
        /* Key press logic, e.g. send character output or execute key press */
    };
}
```

But I was wondering if I couldn't do it in a more organised way. I watched [this tutorial about routed events](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cx6YE86XzYE) to work with custom `ICommand`s but unfortunately I couldn't make it work in a custom control. (Until `mm8` pointed out a way to do it after all)

Comment: Does that mean you have multiple classes derived from Button? For what reason?

Comment: You can use attached properties. Similar to how children tells `Grid` which `Row` and `Column` they occupy, you can tell your keyboard thingie how it should behave.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, I currently derived a `OutputKey` (char output), `LeftKey` (navigation), `RightKey` (navigation) and `BackSpaceKey` but they're annoying to manage and to update if needed.

Comment: @Sinatr Ideally, I would create one type of `KeyboardKey` derived from `Button` and give them custom commands, but I'm not sure how. Could you point me to an example where an attached property is used in a custom control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom class and add [dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) to it. Something like this:

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeCommandProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SomeCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomButton));

    public ICommand SomeCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SomeCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomeCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        base.OnClick();
        //do something based on the property value...
        if (SomeCommand != null)
            SomeCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

You could then set the dependency properties everywhere where you use the control, e.g.:

```
<local:CustomButton Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" />
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I just saw your answer! I suppose I can define my command that derives from `ICommand` in a separate file right?

Comment: You can set the `SomeCommand` property to any object that implements `ICommand`, including your own custom commands. I am not sure how this is related to your original question though.

Comment: Well, I was planning to write a `SendCharacterCommand` and `KeyPressCommand` for the two types of buttons I would have. I just didn't know it was possible to link them this easily!

Comment: Well, the two commands require different parameters, that's why I thought it would be nice to use two buttons.

Comment: Yeah it's true, I'm going to mention the use of `ICommand` more explicitly. I saw a tutorial about them but they didn't seem to work when I tried them at first.

Comment: In my original question.

Comment: @JansthcirlU: Don't change the original question after it has been answered. Ask a new if you have another issue.

Comment: I'm simply adding more information about the YouTube link I've posted and how I've tried to do something similar without success. It's not a different question.

Comment: Where did I ever mention attached properties? Someone in the comments suggested it to me but I hadn't even heard of them.

Comment: I mentioned them in my answer. Do they help you or not? What is your question exactly?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to hook up the commands using this approach. If you override `OnClick` and include a call to execute the command, you are expecting to know the parameters ahead of time, right? Is there a way to execute a command using your method while still allowing to include a parameter in the `xaml`?

Comment: Add a command parameter property next to the command property then? My answer shows how to set the command parameter so I am not sure what you mean by "hook up the command"...?

Comment: No, what I mean is that in your `OnClick` method, you write `SomeCommand.Execute(null)`, implying it doesn't need any command parameters. But what if I wanted to execute a command that does use a parameter upon clicking?

Comment: Then you should of course add *another* dependency property for the parameter and use it in your click event handler: `SomeCommand.Execute(SomeParameter)`.

Comment: Hmm I see, so there's no way to do it from the xaml then? For example something like `Command="{Binding ExampleCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SomeParameter}" />`